# TeX Live in .iso or .exe file

Tags: installing, texlive

Is there a way to get TeX Live in a `.iso` or `.exe` file with all required files and packages instead of [downloading the net downloader/installer](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl.zip)?

I would download TeX Live just one time, and install it where I need without waiting every time long hours for the download. Also if the TeX Live version couldn't be the last; one time that I have installed I can update it with the TeX Live Manager...

Comment: It is not a bad thing that you get a frozen version of TeX Live. Sometimes updates can break your work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TeX Live is available as "one huge ISO file" from the TUG website [Acquiring TeX Live as an ISO image](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html). It is also available in a number of smaller, yet still [big tarballs](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-tar.html). It is also available as a [`.torrent`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/files/texlive2012.torrent).

Both these methods have a fixed image available for download, so packages may have been updated after the official release and therefore still require packages to be updated after installation.

Comment: Aren't recommended because this methods don't ensure the updated version of the various files, but if I update all with the TeX Live Manager is the same thing, right? Another thing, are there some differences between `texlive2012-20120701.iso` and this other `texlive2012.iso`?

Comment: @FormlessCloud: Yes, it would be the same thing. Updating via [`tlmgr`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html) will give you the most up-to-date packages from the downloaded repository. I doubt there's a difference in the `.iso` releases. The release date for TeX Live 2012 was July 8, 2012, after which the DVD, ISO, TARball and Torrent files should be fixed. Since I downloaded TL 2012 via the net installer, I don't know much more.

Comment: One of the mirrors says it’s the same file. http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/Images/

Comment: Were you able to install from the .iso without internet? Is it smooth?